# Store float value with Entity Framework throws exception

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to store gps values, longitude and latitude, using .Net Core API and Entity Framework.

This is the table and has some records:

[image: Tabla destinos]

This is the model

```
public class Destinos
{
        [Key]
        public int idDestino { get; set; }
        public String nombreDestino { get; set; }
        public String direccionDestino { get; set; }
        public float longitudDestino { get; set; }
        public float latitudDestino { get; set; }
        public String referenciaDestino { get; set; }
}
```

When running this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Destinos> GettDestinos()
{
      return _context.tDestinos;
}
```

I get this exception

[image]

Do you guys have any clue or workaround for this?

Comment: Because you allow null's in your database try making the float as `float?` or `double?` in your `Destinos` class

Comment: I have just tried with double and it works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) is a 32-bit, single-precision floating point number, and is a synonym for System.Single.  In SQL Server [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a synonym for `float(53)` a 64-bit double-precision floating point number.

C# `float` = SQL Server's `real` aka `float(24)`

C# `double` = SQL Server's `float`

So the correct mapping for a SQL Server nullable float is `Nullable<System.Double>` aka `double?`

```
public class Destinos
{
        [Key]
        public int idDestino { get; set; }
        public String nombreDestino { get; set; }
        public String direccionDestino { get; set; }
        public double? longitudDestino { get; set; }
        public double? latitudDestino { get; set; }
        public String referenciaDestino { get; set; }
}
```